# send file content with a message queue C

Tags: c, process, ipc, message-queue

I'm looking for the best way to read a file and send the contents via a message queue.
I tried to read the file line by line and insert the contents of the file into an array, but maybe not the best way.
I was wondering is there another way, perhaps it's better to send the whole file and then read it to the process that receives it.
Do you have any suggestions?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As I read it there is hardly a difference between the per line array send method and the full file send method. You are only spreading the load on the network that way. Unless the receiving party has a limited CPU and memory cache it does not increase the overall system performance.

I would suggest looking into parsing the whole file for relevant data. Then send this new data via a message queue. Unless of course the program reading the file has limited resources, while the receiving end has enough resources and the traffic load on the network isn't an issue.

Comment: I thank you for your reply.
I am not sure I understand what what you tell me.
To be more clear, I would like to know if to send the contents of a file. txt on a message queue is better to send the text of the file (after reading it and added to an array), or if there is another better way, such as included in the message structure a pointer to the file or the entire file (even though I do not know how ..)

Comment: I'm sorry, I was thinking about message queue's over ethernet. If the sender and receiver are two different processes (not threads) sending a pointer will most likely give a segmentation fault. Here (http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node25.html) they use arrays as well, so just make a large enough buffer in the struct for most of your files if you wish to send it all. Maybe http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/ can help with that. However, my suggestion would still be to compress the data.